# .NET Core 6.0 Access secrets.json from repository class

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a .NET Core 6.0 Web API project and I'd like to be able to read values from the secrets.json file in order to build the database connection string from my repository class.  I am able to read the values from Program.cs but do not know how to do the same from my repository class.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Do I need to inject IConfiguration and if so how?

Comment: My controller calls the repository to get the data.  How do I access the secrets from the repository?

Comment: Use Dependency Injection. Here is clearly explained how to do it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows#read-the-secret-via-the-configuration-api